# Multiple different layouts in adapter

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-databinding

I have a small problem. I am trying to show multiple different layouts in my RecyclerView. I managed to do this in two different ways. But i feel like my code and logic could look so much better

My project itself is following the MVVM design pattern. So i am using the native data binding. This is why my logic is becoming a problem.

**First way of doing it**

The first way i tried to do this is just to cramp up everything into a big layout file. Then just hide and show depending on what type of post it was.

```
  private void onBindImagePost(CommentFeedViewHolder holder, CommentFeedItem item) {
    holder.mBinding.adapterCommentFeedDraweeView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.mBinding.adapterCommentFeedTopic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.mBinding.adapterCommentFeedYoutubeContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.mBinding.adapterCommentFeedVideoContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.mBinding.adapterCommentFeedPieChartContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.mBinding.adapterCommentFeedDraweeView.setImageURI(item.getUri());
  }
```

So firstly i just show and hide the views that are in use and is not. I also added extra logic to some views.

This solution felt very bad since it is a lot of hardcoding included into it and business logic was added to the fragment.

**Second way of doing it**

I added a new layout file for each post. They all have they're own binding.
This minimized the code.

```
    if (item.getType() == POST_TEXT) {
        AdapterFeedType1Binding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.adapter_feed_type_1,holder.binding.mainFrame,true);
        binding.setGameFeedItem(item);
    }
```

But is there a better way? So i dont have to create a new binding class for every type of post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second option is better. There will still be multiple generated binding classes, but you can access them through a single interface if you do it like this:

```
private static final int[] LAYOUT_IDS = {
    R.layout.adapter_feed_type_1,
    R.layout.adapter_feed_type_2,
    ...};


public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    int layoutId = LAYOUT_IDS[viewType];
    ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layoutId,
        parent, false);
    MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(binding);
    return viewHolder;
}

public void onBindViewHolder (MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Item item = getItemAtPosition(position); // your method
    holder.binding.setVariable(BR.gameFeedItem, item);
    holder.binding.executePendingBindings();
}
```

As long as all variables are named the same (`gameFeedItem` in this case), this system will work. I've assumed a `ViewHolder` named `MyViewHolder` that has the Binding as a public final field.

Comment: ViewDataBinding was exactly what i where looking for but failed to find. Thanks a lot. This helped me create a clean solution